# Python-1D indice link with 2D array location

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

#### Introduction

Sometimes, I want to get the value of an 2-d array at a random location.
For example, there is an array **`data`** in the shape of (20,20). There is a random number-pair (5,5). Then, I get the data[5,5] as my target value.

On the purpose of using genetic algorithm. I want to get the samples from an 2-d array as several  individuals.  **So, I want to generate an linked table which connect an 1d value to 2d position.**

#### My attempt

```
## data was the 2-d array in the shape of 20x20
data = np.random.randint(0,1000,400)
data = data.reshape(20,20)

## direction was my linked table
direction = {"Indice":[],"X":[],"Y":[]}
k = 0
for i in range(0,data.shape[0],1):
    for j in range(0,data.shape[1],1):
        k+=1
        direction["Indice"].append(k)
        direction["X"].append(j)
        direction["Y"].append(i)
direction = pd.DataFrame(direction)   

## generate an random int and connect with the 2-d value.  
loc = np.random.randint(0,400)  
XX = np.array(direction[direction.Indice == loc ].X)
YY = np.array(direction[direction.Indice == loc ].Y)
target_value = data[YY,XX]
```

#### My question

Are there any neat way to achieve my attempt?
Any advice would be appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to make `data` 1-dimensional, then index it using the flat index `loc`:

```
target_value = data.ravel()[loc-1]
```

---

Or, if you want `XX` and `YY`, perhaps you are looking for [`np.unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html). It maps a flat index or an array of flat indices to a tuple of coordinates.

For example, instead of building the `direction` DataFrame, you could use

```
np.unravel_index(loc-1, data.shape)
```

instead of

```
XX = np.array(direction[direction.Indice == loc ].X)
YY = np.array(direction[direction.Indice == loc ].Y)
```

Then you could define `target_value` as :

```
target_value = data[np.unravel_index(loc-1, data.shape)]
```

---

Alternatively, to simply get a random value from the 2D array `data`, you could use

```
target_value = np.random.choice(data.flat)
```

Or to get `N` random values, use

```
target_values = np.random.choice(data.flat, size=(N,))
```

---

*Why the minus one in `loc-1`*:

In your original code, the `direction['Indice']` column uses `k` values which
start at 1, not 0. So when `loc` equals 1, the 0th-indexed row of `direction` is
selected. I used `loc-1` to make

```
target_value = data[np.unravel_index(loc-1, data.shape)]
```

return the same result that

```
XX = np.array(direction[direction.Indice == loc ].X)
YY = np.array(direction[direction.Indice == loc ].Y)
target_value = data[YY,XX]
```

returns. Note however, that if `loc` equals 0, then `np.unravel_index(-1, data.shape)` raises a `ValueError`, while your original code would return an empty array for `target_value`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By the way, why the `loc` need to minus 1. I tried `np.unravel_index(loc, data.shape)`. The location shows well.

Comment: I used `loc-1` to make my result consistent with your code -- (except when `loc=0`). See above for an elaboration. If all you really want is a random choice then you do not need to subtract one.

Comment: Thanks, that's my fault. I have understood.